# QUESTION abt current

Tags: power

if we use a motor( Nema 17) instead of a resistor as a load, how do we know how much current is it drawing? ( if it is hooked up to a power supply of 12V)

Comment: A NEMA 17 is a stepper motor. You can't just connect it to 12V dc, you need a driver.

Comment: Connect an ammeter, read the current?

Comment: Measure the DC resistance of the motor. NEMA 17 is a form factor but I've never seen a plain old DC motor in that form factor, only steppers,, so you don't need to worry about the back EMF from a running motor. (The ones I've seen have fairly low resistance, so they will burn out pretty quick from 12V).